# Eclipse の EGit から、 `diff` / `merge` コマンドを `FETCH_HEAD` に対して実行する方法

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

Eclipse(EGit)を使用してGitのdiff/mergeコマンドをFETCH_HEADに対して実行する方法を教えて下さい。

リモートリポジトリから「fetch」するとローカルに「FETCH_HEAD」が作成されるのですが、
referenceに対して「Merge」(Gitのmerge）や「Synchronize with Workspace」（Gitのdiff）ができずに困っております。
（手順を下記にまとめました。）

> 1. Local, Tracking, HEAD 全て "e942b47"である事を確認。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>
> 2. Eclipse上で"Fetch From Upstream"を実行。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>
> 3. RemoteとFETCH_HEADが"012d13d"に更新されたことを確認。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>
> 4. FETCH_HEAD上で右クリックをしても「merge」や「Synchronize with Workspace」が表示されない。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>
> 5. Remote Branchの上で右クリックをすると同メニューが表示される。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

EGitにあまり詳しく無いのでそもそもの仕様なのでしょうか。  
何かご存知であればご指摘いただければと思います。  
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Git Historyを開いて、その中の`FETCH_HEAD`が付いているコミットを選択して右クリック、そこで`merge`を選択します。

これでどうでしょうか？

---

（追記）

すみません、説明が足りませんでした。

プロジェクトを選択した状態で、`Team`→`Show in History`して、History Viewの右上にある三角のメニューから`Show`→`Additional Refs`をたどって有効にすると、`FETCH_HEAD`が表示されると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。  
御礼が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。    

Git Historyとは`History` Viewの事でお間違いなかったでしょうか？
確認してみたのですが、`Fetch from Upstream`をした後にもGitのHistoryには`FETCH_HEAD`が表示されておりませんでした。
Remote Branchとは`merge`や`diff`できるのでその方法で対応したいと思います。

Comment: 説明が非常に分かりにくくて申し訳ありませんでした。
あと表示設定を変える必要がありましたのでそれも書きました。